# What's the right method signatures for Aurelia's pipeline

Tags: typescript, aurelia

> You can create your own pipeline steps using addPipelineStep, but the step's name must match one of the pipeline's slots, the default slots in order are authorize, preActivate, preRender, and postRender. Aurelia also has functions for creating a pipeline step for these slots.
>
> authorize is called between loading the route's step and calling the route view-model' canActivate function if defined.
> preActivate is called between the route view-model' canActivate function and the previous route view-model's deactivate function if defined.
> preRender is called between the route view-model's activate function and before the component is rendered/composed.
> postRender is called after the component has been render/composed

so is it `public canActivate(): void {`? `public canActivate(): boolean {`? etc.

Comment: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/router/latest/interface/RoutableComponentCanActivate

Answer (score 1):

The `step` must have a `run` method that returns a `Promise` of a *navigation result*.

```
export class MyStep {
  run(routingContext, next) {

    // do something here!

    return next();
  }
}
```

somewhere else:

```
this.router.configure(config => 
  config.addPipelineStep('authorize', new MyStep ()));
```

The *navigation result* object is an object with a `completed` attribute and/or an `output` attribute. `result.output` can be an `Error` or an object with the `navigate` method.

See the code here to see what the router expects your step Promise to return:  https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/34119d1ce827f10fe5d3c7c97133d83ad922eab6/src/app-router.js#L174